# An elegant way to display "elapsed time" for a set of instructions in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performancecounter, database-performance

I have several stages in a stored procedure and am currently able to display the elapsed time in a very primitive way, by substracting `DATETIME` values.

Would you know / recommend a more elegant way? (I guess RAISERROR is still the best way to display the label containing the elapsed time in a synchronous way)

Comment: You say "SQL" (as in *Structured Query Language*), but from the question, it seems what you really mean is "SQL Server" - the Microsoft relational database product - right?

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for asking. Indeed, I am more interested in Transac SQL replies :)

Comment: What exactly is "primitive" about your current implementation and what does "elegant" mean? It appears that you already have a working solution, so what specific weaknesses or issues does it have?

Comment: It depends on what you're looking to do with it, but "set statistics time on" might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Ben Thul: I'd like to be able to look for timing messages in the Std output, after I execute a long Stored Procedure, to see how long each of its stages has taken.